# Adding Brunel to DSX(Toree)

Tags: scala, data-science-experience, apache-toree

I am using IBM's Data Science Experience (DSX) and want to show some visualizations with Scala.

According to [datascience - visualization](https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/visualization-parent.html) I have 3 options, Pixiedust, Brunel and Lightning.

As far as I saw Lightning is a WIP and requires a server(?) to run the visualizations, Pixiedust's support of Scala is only from inside a Jupyter notebook so I am left with Brunel.

I follow the instructions from [Brunel's Github page](https://github.com/Brunel-Visualization/Brunel/tree/master/spark-kernel), and run the following command to add Brunel to the notebook

```
%AddJar -magic https://brunelvis.org/jar/spark-kernel-brunel-all-2.2.jar
```

I also tried adding the `-f` flag and changing Brunel's version to 2.3 following some answers I found online but I am getting the same error:

```
Starting download from https://brunelvis.org/jar/spark-kernel-brunel-all-2.3.jar
Finished download of spark-kernel-brunel-all-2.3.jar

Magic Addjar failed to execute with error: 
org/apache/toree/magic/CellMagic
```

Any suggestions what might fix the problem? or maybe where to look for the rest of the log?

P.S I have no particular favor for Brunel and if there is a clean way to show other visualization in DSX I would gladly use it.

Comment: Did you use the Scala kernel for Spark 2.1? The kernel for Spark 1.6 uses a different version of Scala.

Comment: @RolandWeber yes I did, the language of the notebook is Scala 2.11